# C# Convert nested groups to List<MyObject>

Tags: c#, linq

So here is a bunch of classes that will end up being grouped.

```
public class Component
{
    public string Name { get; set;}

    public int ComponentType { get; set; }

    public float Range { get; set; }
}

public class ComponentGroup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Type of component in the group
    /// </summary>
    public int Type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// List of Components
    /// </summary>
    public List<Component> Components { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Range
    /// </summary>
    public float Range { get; set; }
}

public class ComponentGroupType
{
    public ComponentType ComponentType { get; set; }
    public List<ComponentGroup> ComponentGroups { get; set; }

    public ComponentGroupType()
    {
        ComponentGroups = new List<ComponentGroup>();
    }

    public ComponentGroupType(List<ComponentGroup> componentGroups )
    {
        ComponentGroups = componentGroups;
    }
}
```

Now lets say I have `List<Component>` which is populated like so.

```
Component() { Name = "A", ComponentType = 1, Range = 10000 }
Component() { Name = "B", ComponentType = 1, Range = 10000 }
Component() { Name = "C", ComponentType = 1, Range = 10000 }
Component() { Name = "D", ComponentType = 1, Range = 1000 }
Component() { Name = "E", ComponentType = 1, Range = 1000 }
Component() { Name = "F", ComponentType = 2, Range = 1000000 }
Component() { Name = "G", ComponentType = 2, Range = 1000000 }
Component() { Name = "H", ComponentType = 3, Range = 1000000 }
```

What I want to do is group the items by `ComponentType` and then by `Range` which means I should end up with something like this.

```
List<ComponentGroupType>
 |- ComponentGroupType() ComponentType = 1 
    |-- ComponentGroup() Range = 10000
        |--- Component() { Name = "A", ComponentType = 1, Range = 10000 }
        |--- Component() { Name = "B", ComponentType = 1, Range = 10000 }
        |--- Component() { Name = "C", ComponentType = 1, Range = 10000 }
    |-- ComponentGroup() Range = 1000
        |--- Component() { Name = "D", ComponentType = 1, Range = 1000 }
        |--- Component() { Name = "E", ComponentType = 1, Range = 1000 }

|- ComponentGroupType() ComponentType = 2
    |-- ComponentGroup() Range = 1000000
        |--- Component() { Name = "F", ComponentType = 2, Range = 1000000 }
        |--- Component() { Name = "G", ComponentType = 2, Range = 1000000 }

|- ComponentGroupType() ComponentType = 3
        |-- ComponentGroup() Range = 1000000
        |--- Component() { Name = "H", ComponentType = 3, Range = 1000000 }
```

Sorry for the poor representation but hopefully you get an idea of how they are grouped.

So here is my nested grouping code which seems to do the grouping part ok.

```
var groups = from component in _components
             group component by component.ComponentType into group1
             from group2 in 
                 (from component in group1
                 group component by component.Range)
             group group2 by group1.Key;
```

What I want is to convert the grouping data to the above types i.e. `groups` is `TypeOf(List<ComponentGroupType>)` which contains a lists of `ComponentGroups` which contains lists of `Component` etc etc.

Comment: Have a look at LINQ's `SelectMany`

Comment: It _sounds_ like you are asking how to use a IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> (ie what group by produces) to produce your custom types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the LINQ query for producing the desired result is more natural than the nested grouping example. Just do exactly what you want - group by `ComponentType`, then by `Range`:

```
var groups = (
    from component in _components
    group component by component.ComponentType into typeGroup
    select new ComponentGroupType
    {
        ComponentType = typeGroup.Key,
        ComponentGroups = (
           from component in typeGroup
           group component by component.Range into rangeGroup
           select new ComponentGroup
           {
               Type = typeGroup.Key,
               Range = rangeGroup.Key,
               Components = rangeGroup.ToList()
           }
       ).ToList()
    }
).ToList();
```